# If using a function in a case, does it run on each condition and result or is cached?

Tags: postgresql

In this example:

```
select case when someFunction() is null or someFunction() = 0 then 999 else someFunction() end
```

someFunction() runs three times or just one?

Comment: Is `somefunction` `IMMUTABLE`, `STABLE` or `VOLATILE`? Does it take no arguments, like in your example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It runs every time you call it, in your case three times.

So rewrite the function that makes the case superfluous.